# Как мне с сайта (который НЕ стоит на IIS) переслать запрос на web-сервер, оттуда к 1С и потом обратно?

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, 1с, веб-сервер, iis

Я впервые сталкиваюсь с web-сервером **IIS** и бд на базе **1С:Предприятие**.

Есть **сайт написанный на php** и есть бд **1С** которая стоит на сервере **IIS**. Мне нужно с сайта направить запрос в бд, т.е.  **<САЙТ>** ---> **<*IIS*>** ---> **<*1C*>**

С чего мне вообще начать? Как мне с **сайта** (*!!!который НЕ стоит на **ISS**!!!*) переслать запрос на web-сервер, оттуда к **1С** и потом обратно?

Comment: как насчет использования тега iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от того, какая у тебя конфигурация 1С. Дело в том, что не любое прикладное решение поддерживает веб-сервисы. Их поддерживают только более поздние версии, основанные на управляемых формах. Точно знаю, что УТ 11, 1С ЕРП поддерживают. Но при наличии в распоряжении нормального 1Сника это можно реализовать и на старых конфигурациях, главное, чтобы была версия от 8.2 и выше. 
Вот ещё подборка статей: http://www.bizkit.ru/2013/05/24/1722/

Как вариант, можно прицепить обмен к [стандартному обмену с сайтом (Битрикс)](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=42&CHAPTER_ID=04923). Обмен идёт в формате CML, обмен идет в одностороннем порядке, 1С по расписанию (если серверная) или по нажатию на кнопку "Выполнить обмен данными" стучится на сайт, указанный в настройках, выгружает туда товары, остатки и забирает заказы. Такой обмен поддерживается большинством типовых конфигураций.

Answer (score 1):

`1С` сейчас совершенствует  `REST` интерфейс приложения, автоматически генерируемый платформой, и протокол обмена `ODATA` версии `3`.
С недавнего времени появилась возможность обмениваться, используя `JSON`. На просторах интернета мало информации по использованию `Linq` для `ODATA` для `1С`.
Поэтому решил поделиться опытом.

`ODATA` это открытый веб-протокол для запроса и обновления данных. Он позволяет оперировать данными, используя в качестве запросов `HTTP-команды`. 
Затем в `VS` Добавить ссылку на службу используя `URI`

```
http://{АдресВебСервера}/{ИмяПубликации}/odata/standard.odata/$metadata
```

Получаем описание классов доступ и доступ к `ODATA` например так

```
var uriString = @"http://localhost/LinqBD/odata/standard.odata/";

var context = new ServiceReference1.EnterpriseV8(new Uri(uriString));

context.Format.UseJson();

var query = context.CreateQuery<ServiceReference1.Catalog_Тестовый>(@"Catalog_Тестовый")
```

если не использовать `context.Format.UseJson()` то данные будут присылаться в формате `XML`

Можно получить один элемент по ключу

```
var query = context.CreateQuery<ServiceReference1.Catalog_Тестовый>(@"Catalog_Тестовый(guid'aada18ad-5308-11e5-8e05-c86000c70663')");
```

Можно добавлять фильтры например

```
var query = context.CreateQuery<ServiceReference1.Catalog_Тестовый>(@"Catalog_Тестовый").AddQueryOption("$filter", "Число le 100");
```

Но проще использовать доступ к `ODATA` через `Linq`. Например

```
var result = (from Тестовыйin context.Catalog_Тестовый
                          where Тестовый.Число < 500
                          select Тестовый).ToList();

var result = (from Тестовыйin context.Catalog_Тестовый
                          where Тестовый.Ref_Key == newGuid("aada18ad-5308-11e5-8e05-c86000c70663")
                          select Тестовый).SingleOrDefault();
```

То есть можно работать с `ODATA` полностью на `Linq`

Подгрузка ссылочных реквизитов

```
var ПустаяСсылка = new Guid("00000000 - 0000 - 0000 - 0000 - 000000000000");

            string НоменклатураНаименование = "";

            if (result.РеквизитСправочник_Key != ПустаяСсылка)
            {
                context.LoadProperty(result, "РеквизитСправочник");
                НоменклатураНаименование = result.РеквизитСправочник.Description;
            }
```

Для Неопределенных типов Можно создать функцию

```
object ПолучитьНеопределенныйТип(ServiceReference1.EnterpriseV8 context, string значение, stringТип)
        {
            switch (Тип)
            {
                case "StandardODATA.Undefined":
                    return null;
                case "StandardODATA.Catalog_Номенклатура":
                    return context.Catalog_Номенклатура.Where(Тестовый => Тестовый.Ref_Key == new Guid(значение)).SingleOrDefault();
                case "Edm.Double":
                    return Double.Parse(значение, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                …..
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Ииспользовать

```
dynamic ЛюбаяССылка = ПолучитьНеопределенныйТип(context, result.ЛюбаяСсылка, result.ЛюбаяСсылка_Type);

dynamic НеСсылочный = ПолучитьНеопределенныйТип(context, result.НеопределенныйНеССылочный, result.НеопределенныйНеССылочный_Type);
```

По сути некая замена `COM`.

Полезные ссылки для запросов `ODATA`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/dd673933(v=vs.100).aspx

Обновление, добавление и удаление записей

Хотя странно, что 1С применяет для чисел `Double` вместо `Decimal`

Да есть возможность в `ODATA` сразу подгружать нужные свойства

```
 var result = (from Тестовый in context.Catalog_Тестовый.Expand("РеквизитСправочник") 
                              where Тестовый.Ref_Key == new Guid("aada18ad-5308-11e5-8e05-c86000c70663") 
                              select Тестовый).SingleOrDefault();
```

Но пока в `1С` Параметр `$expand` не поддерживается"

Хотя все течет все изменяется `1С` может добавить этот параметр

Answer (score 0):

Есть пара вариантов интеграции с 1С.

Первый - через [веб-сервисы](http://v8.1c.ru/overview/Term_000000273.htm). PHP-код сайта будет обращаться через SOAP к веб-сервисам предоставляемым 1С. Для этого они должны быть доступны извне (1С обычно располагается в локальной сети). Надо понимать чем это может грозить, да и не каждый бухгалтер позволит такое вытворять со "своей 1Ской".

Второй вариант - держать на сайте копию минимально необходимых данных из 1С. При этом периодически синхронизироваться с основной базой. Либо через те же веб-сервисы, либо через выгружаемые из 1С файлы в любой формат (csv, xml), которые затем загружаются на сайт (и в обратную сторону, если потребуется). Удобен тем, что 1С можно не выставлять наружу.

Все зависит от конкретной задачи, которую требуется решить.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно механизм обмена неким сайтом и 1с-кой инициируется самой 1с-кой. Если сайт написан с использованием какой-либо популярной CMS или если это популярное web-приложение, то модуль обмена уже должен быть в сети.
Для более полного ответа на вопрос необходимо больше данных о самой 1с-ке и о сайте (какой движок, может ссылка на сам сайт).
Кстати, то, что используется IIS как WEB-сервер, не имеет в вопросе обмена никакого влияния. Это мог быть и Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Вэб сервисы,HTTP- сервисы ODATA

Если пишешь на ASP.Net то есть несколько вариантов Odata
http://infostart.ru/public/403524/

В 1С кроме Вэб сервисов есть HTTP сервисы. К сожалению, есть ограничения по ссылкам. Еще есть вариант с прямым доступом к SQL, например, http://infostart.ru/public/393228/

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение. Уверен, если вы приведете конкретный пример в теле вашего вопроса, ваши коллеги будут вам благодарны.