# 1c взаимодействие с java

Tags: java, 1с

На предприятии есть `1с 8.2` конфигурация управление торговлей. Хочу написать на android клиент для менеджеров, чтобы они могли со своих телефонов сбрасывать заявки сразу в 1с.

Подскажите с помощью чего это лучше провернуть, готовое решение от 1с не предлагать, ибо хочется своими руками и без участи `программистов 1с`. Первое что мне пришло в голову, напрямую лепить данные в базу 1с, которая развёрнута с помощью *Microsoft SQL Server*, но я не уверен что 1с сможет эти данные подхватывать.

Может есть готовое API или ещё что то?

Comment: Вот чисто беспроблемный варианты - это сделать почтовый ящик, и отправлять заявки сгенерированные в клиенте на него, а чтобы 1С их забирала. Или можно через dropbox попробовать. А в SQL писать можно конечно, но как уже сказали структура специфическая + встает вопрос а как ты из внешки будешь цепляться ? Вряд ли ИТшники согласятся Скуль на котором база предприятия светить во внешку.

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin  Заявки по почте? Напишите более развёрнутый ответ, отмечу как правильный. Меня интересует в каком формате отправлять эти заявки? Нужно ли будет допиливать 1с?

Comment: А зачем? Рынок сбыта твоих рабочих часов? Кто тебе ставит бизнеспроцесс? Я Знаю до десятка Андроидных приложений с разной функциональностью работающих с 1с. И развивающихся уже много лет. Чем твое будет лучше. Разве что дипломная, курсовая работа.

Comment: Лучше напиши универсальную интеграцию для зооппарка конф 1с. С одним из уже СОСТОЯВЩИХСЯ приложений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот чисто беспроблемный варианты - это сделать почтовый ящик, и отправлять заявки сгенерированные в клиенте на него, а чтобы 1С их забирала. Или можно через dropbox попробовать. А в SQL писать можно конечно, но как уже сказали структура специфическая + встает вопрос а как ты из внешки будешь цепляться ? Вряд ли ИТшники согласятся Скуль на котором база предприятия светить во внешку.

Формат на ваше усмотрение. Делаете почтовый ящик какой-то отдельный для данных задач, из Androida легко отправить на почту. В 1с, нужно сделать регламентное задание (фоновое), которое будет читать данные и формировать документ Заявок (примеров чтения из почтового ящика на infostart.ru дофига). Все равно на стороне 1С придется делать фоновое задание, которое преобразует входящие данные в удобоваримый 1Совский вид. Ну просто нет шансов что вы на уровне таблиц sql простроите все связи между элементами данных так же, как это требуется для работы самой 1С, это лучше делать уже через встроенные 1Совские механизмы.

Comment: Спасибо,я и сам не очень то хотел возиться с sql, попробую подробнее изучить то что вы предложили.

Answer (score 1):

Привет, да твой вариант вполне рабочий, единственный момент что у 1с своеобразная структура базы, но все волне решаемо. Есть еще вариант сделать WebApi сервер, например на битрексе, который будет принимать данные от пользователей и выгружать уже их в 1с. Правда в данном случае появится задержка между отправкой и появлении в 1с

Comment: насчёт задержек ничего страшного. Попробую развернуть тестовую базу и конфигурацию, важно чтобы 1с автоматически подхватывала данные из базы.

Comment: Все настраивается)

Answer (score 1):

1С нормально работает и с почтой, и с XML, и с базами данных. Т.е. можно и вариант с почтой, но я бы лучше делал либо файлы в XML, либо даже создал бы отдельно стоящую базу данных, куда скидывал бы заявки, а в 1С эту базу подсоединил бы как внешний источник данных, и оттуда их подхватывал. Всё-таки XML и базы данных как-то надёжнее и удобнее писем, по-моему.

И без программистов 1С не получится ни один из вариантов, в том числе и предложенных выше, потому что 1С нужно "научить" принимать заявки в виде письма, т.е. написать механизм конвертации входящий инфы в заявки.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас занимаюсь разбором механизмов 1с, думаю покопаю в сторону дополнительной БД.

Answer (score 1):

Платформа 8.3 позволяет вести разработку под android. Общение между мобильным клиентом и самой 1С происходит с использованием web-сервисов, создаваемых на стороне рабочей БД. Данный механизм является наиболее правильным т.к. обеспечивает наибольшую скорость обмена данными. Работать напрямую с SQL нельзя т.к. ОЧЕНЬ ОПАСНО.
А использовать web-сервисы можно как для связки с другой 1С или мобильными клиентами 1С, так и вообще с любой системой. Это может быть и приложение под Android или iOS, и просто сайт на PHP или ASP.NET, и любое другое приложение.

Answer (score 0):

Решений можно подобрать очень много. От самых простых, до самых сложных, в зависимости от уже имеющейся инфраструктуры.

1. Обмен файлами по ftp, mail, http. Форматы: xml, json, свой велосипед.
2. Работа с 1С из любого языка через OLE с использованием пула соединений для скорости.[Работа с 1С через OLE](http://infostart.ru/public/83859/)
3. Можно организовать web-сервер и общаться с 1С с помощью встроенных в платформу web-сервисов [Использование внешних web-сервисов в 1С:Предприятие 8](http://kb.mista.ru/article.php?id=473).

Answer (score 0):

Кроме HTTP и Веб сервисов можно использовать WebSocket и в частности SignalR
[1C Messenger для отправки сообщений, файлов и обмена данными между пользователями 1С, вэб страницы, мобильными приложениями а ля Skype, WhatsApp](http://infostart.ru/public/434771/)

Там есть примеры и на Xamarin скачать примеры можно здесь https://yadi.sk/d/G67GAnc-nrUJ9

Кроме того сейчас модно использовать ODATA [Как мне с сайта (который НЕ стоит на IIS) переслать запрос на web-сервер, оттуда к 1С и потом обратно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434111/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%9d%d0%95-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-iis-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-web-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0/467102#467102)